# Rogue DHCP can't be found

Tags: networking

Over the last 3 weeks I have been trying to find a rogue DHCP server on my network but have been stumped! It is offering IP Addresses that do not work with my network so any device that needs a Dynamic Address is getting one from the Rogue DHCP. I need help to find and destroy this thing!

My Main Router is the only valid DHCP Server and is 192.168.0.1 which offers a range of 192.160.0.150-199. This ROGUE DHCP claims to be coming from 192.168.0.20 and offering an IP Address in the range of 10.255.255.* which is messing up EVERYTHING on my network unless I assign a static IP Address to it.

My network is a single AD Server on Windows 2008R2, 3 other physical servers (1-2008R2 and 2 2012R2) about 4 Hypervisor Machines, 3 laptops and a Windows 7 box.

I can't ping the rouge 192.160.0.20 IP and I can't see it in the ARP -A output so I can't get it's MAC address. I'm hoping that someone reading this post has come across this before.

Comment: This question might belong better on Server Fault or Super User as it is not directly related to programming.

Comment: I've posted an answer but am voting to close since this doesn't belong here

Answer (score 0):

Run a sniffer on a system that is sending out DHCP requests.  Look at the source MAC address in the responding packets from the rogue DHCP server.  Next, go to the switches and pull the MAC addresses that are currently mapped to the ports in the CAM table to figure out which port it's connected to.

If you follow that wire to the end you'll find your server.

Comment: Thanks. I'll post this on Server Fault. There is no MAC Address as I can't ping it since the rogue is on a different subnet. I think this is some sort of Trojan that has infected all the machines on my network.

Comment: It must have a MAC address.  You're not pinging it.  You're looking at the response packets to see what MAC is in them.  From that, you're looking at the CAM tables in the switches to figure out which port that MAC is on.